# Algebra math expression translated to python function with 2 inputs and a rounded answer

Tags: python, function, math

Learning math to python conversion. Having trouble translating this math expression to a python function with two inputs (x, y). Help would be appreciated. I will have to catch up on my order of calculations its seems. Also some resources where I can learn more about this myself would be great. Thanks :)

[image: math expression]

The input variables x and y are single values
If a division by zero occurs, raise a ValueError.
Output should be rounded to 2 decimal places.
You can calculate    using the NumPy function np.exp(x)

```
def math_func(x, y):
    math_func = math.pi*np.exp(x))**2 / 4(y)
    return round(math_func, 2)
```

Comment: Why do you want to round the result? If it's a display issue, you shouldn't round the number, but instead use string formatting. For instance, when printing the number, use `'{:.2f}'.format(number)` to only show the first two digits after the decimal point. But this should be in the function that prints, not in the function that makes the mathematical calculations.

Answer (score 3):

The following implements that mathematical function. You forgot to square the `x`. I recommend using parentheses to separate the numerator and denominator. It saves you from having to remember all the operator precedence and associativity rules. Moreover, you need to explicitly write `4 * y` to multiply the two numbers ( `4y` is a `SyntaxError`).

```
from math import exp, pi
def foo(x, y):
    try:
        res = (pi * exp(x * x)) / (4 * y)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise ValueError
    return round(res, 2)

print(foo(2, 5))
```

Output

```
8.58
```

To sample dividing by zero, try `foo(2, 0)`. The traceback message should indicate that a `ZeroDivisionError` occurred and that during handling of that exception, `ValueError` occurred.

Comment: Just execute `foo(0.5, 0)` (after the function definition)? A `ValueError` will be raised.

Comment: Ah, you are using numpy. Do you need to use numpy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244653/discussion-between-pangaman89-and-oda).

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues.

- avoid using the function name as internal variable (here I used `z`)
- you can't make implicit multiplications (use `4*y`, `4(y)` would mean you try to use `4` as a function, which is impossible)
- you had a wrong precedence: e^x^2 is e^(x^2)
- (minor) if you already import `numpy` you can use `numpy.pi`

corrected version

```
def math_func(x, y):
    import numpy as np
    z = np.pi*np.exp(x**2) / (4*y)
    return round(z, 2)

math_func(3, 4)
# 1591.04
```

*Regarding the `ValueError`, unless this is for an assignment (in which case you can use `try`/`except`), it is probably better to keep the `ZeroDivisionError` that is more explicit than the more generic `ValueError`*